# Trying to row reduce a symbolic matrix in SymPy - what simplifying function is needed?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to row reduce a matrix with variables in the last column:

```
s, t = symbols('s t')
S = Matrix(2,3, [2,-1, s, 1, -1/2, t])
```

So, `Matrix([[2, -1, s], [1, -0.500000000000000, t]])`. When row reduced, the second row should be `0 0 t - s/2`, that is, an expression in `s` and `t` (so the matrix is singular unless s = 2t). But SymPy returns:

```
Matrix([[1, -1/2, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072700/why-does-sympy-give-me-the-wrong-answer-when-i-row-reduce-a-symbolic-matrix) gets at this same issue but the solution there (passing `simplify = True` into the `rref` method) doesn't work for me, and I have tried several of the [other possible simplify options](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/simplification.html) with no luck. For example, passing `simplify = cancel` gives me the same result and passing just `cancel` as the first argument gives me the matrix `Matrix([[2, 0, s], [1, 0, t]])`.

What simplifying option should be passed, and how should I invoke it?

Comment: Are you doing `S.rref()`?

Comment: Entering `RowReduce[{{2,-1,s},{1,-1/2,t}}]` into Mathematica likewise gives `{{1,-(1/2),0},{0,0,1}}`. I guess both of them just divide the second row by `t - s/2`, without considering that it could be zero...

Comment: You could try specifying a custom function for `iszerofunc`, see https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.matrices.MatrixReductions.rref.

Comment: Yes, `S.rref()`.

Answer (score 0):

The reduced row echelon form (RREF) by definition has the leading entry of each row normalised to 1:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form

```
In [5]: S
Out[5]: 
⎡2   -1   s⎤
⎢          ⎥
⎣1  -0.5  t⎦

In [6]: S.rref()[0]
Out[6]: 
⎡1  -1/2  0⎤
⎢          ⎥
⎣0   0    1⎦
```

What you are looking for is the (unreduced) row echelon form which SymPy provides as `echelon_form`:

```
In [7]: S.echelon_form()
Out[7]: 
⎡2  -1     s    ⎤
⎢               ⎥
⎣0  0   -s + 2⋅t⎦
```

If you ask for the RREF then SymPy will divide each row by its leading entry and also subtract from all columns above that leading entry. This is not necessarily valid for all possible values of symbolic parameters e.g. it might be that `s = 2*t` but for *generic* values of the parameters this is the correct RREF.

> so the matrix is singular unless s = 2t

It doesn't make sense to talk about rectangular matrices being singular. If the matrix we have here is considered to be the augmented matrix for a system of equations then that system of equations has no solutions unless `s = 2*t`. In that context the unaugmented matrix (i.e. the first two columns of `S`) is singular regardless of the values of `s` and `t`.